# How do I loop a python list input validation?

Tags: python, list, loops, validation, input

```
newcompany = input("Enter Company Name: ")
for stock in portfolioStock:
    if newcompany.lower() == stock[0].lower():
        newcompany = input("Company already exist in the Portfolio\nPlease enter another Company Name: ")
        break
    else:
        newcompany = newcompany.capitalize()
        continue
```

the code above only checks for the input validation once before moving on to my next chunk of code, how do I make it validate the input continuously.
For example, for the input, I enter apple, but I have apple in my list, so it prompts again, but when I input apple again, it just moves on to the next line of code.

```
Enter Company Name: apple
Company already exist in the Portfolio
Please enter another Company Name: apple
Enter market capitalisation of company: Mega, Large or Mid:
```

this is how it looks

next is with the `while` loop

```
newcompany = input("Enter Company Name: ")
while True:
    for stock in portfolioStock:
        if newcompany.lower() == stock[0].lower():
            newcompany = input("Company already exist in the Portfolio\nPlease enter another Company Name: ")
            break
        else:
            newcompany = newcompany.capitalize()
            continue
```

This is how my code looks like with the `while` loop
These are the results

```
Enter Company Name: apple
Company already exist in the Portfolio
Please enter another Company Name: apple
Company already exist in the Portfolio
Please enter another Company Name: samsung
```

it leaves a space below samsung and doesn't continue to the next line of code

Comment: You should use a `while` loop here

Comment: i tried a while loop as well, but it produces the same results :(

Comment: Could you provide what portfolioStock is? I assume it is a list of lists, because your are comparing the input with stock[0]. This, however, only checks if first element in the list is equal to the input. Is that what you want?

Comment: yep portfolioStock is a 2d list, and i want to validate the input with the first item in the list thats in the 2d list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not completely clear to me what you are looking for. Assuming `portfolioStock` is a `list` of lists, this might work for you.

```
newcompany = input("Enter Company Name: ")
for stock in portfolioStock:
  #Convert all elements in list to lowercase
  stock = [x.lower() for x in stock]
  #This loop wil continue as long as the input is equal to any value in stock
  while newcompany.lower() in stock:
    newcompany = input("Company already exist in the Portfolio\nPlease enter another Company Name: ")
  newcompany = newcompany.capitalize()
```

Comment: what is my 2d list contains intergers as well

Answer (score 0):

Use the `while` loop to check if the company already exists, if it does it will keep prompting you for a new name. When there's a new name, it will be added to the list

```
portfolioStock = ["Apple"]
company = input("Enter Company Name: ")
while company.capitalize() in portfolioStock: # e.g. 'Apple' is already in there
    company = input("Company already exist in the Portfolio\nPlease enter another Company Name: ")

portfolioStock.append(company.capitalize())
```

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU MITCHELL OLISLAGERS!!

```
newcompany = input("Enter Company Name: ")
for stock in portfolioStock:
    while newcompany.lower() == stock[0].lower():
        newcompany = input("Company already exist in the Portfolio\nPlease enter another Company Name: ")
    newcompany = newcompany.capitalize()
```

since my portfolioStock is a 2D list with both str and int, i had to edit Mitchell's code a little bit, but it works!!! thank you so much!!

Comment: Great to hear. I can imagine the feeling when your code finally ran as you wanted.

Comment: Your supposed to accept his answer and upvote him not paste it here

Comment: sorry i did not know that :(